# getResources() causes huge use of heap

Tags: android, heap-memory

in my Android App, I want to set a round image to an imageView. And behindt this imageView there is another imageView which becomes the border.

The second imageView (the round border for the first imageView) gets an image via:

```
    public static void setImage(ImageView imgView, Drawable drawable, boolean squareCrop)
    {        
        Bitmap bm = drawableToBitmap(drawable);
        if (squareCrop)
        {          
            Bitmap square = Helfer.cropToSquare(bm);                    
            imgView.setImageBitmap(getCircleBitmap(square));

        }
        else
        {

            imgView.setImageBitmap(getCircleBitmap(bm));
        }
    }
```

When the method is entered the used heap size grows for 30MB. This is what i do not unterstand. The image I load is just white and 1,9kb.

How is it possible that there is this gigant growth in the memory usage? This causes an outOfMemory-Exception. That´s the reason why I need to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: please provide a stack trace of the exception

Comment: it does not direct cause the OOM. But on one test devide there only is 256 MB heap and the largest operations are these shown above. I add an border to 4 images and this does allocate so incredible much memory

Comment: without further information there is little chance that someone will be able to help you. the problem can be within these getcircle methods or at some totally different place, you should also provide the link to the library you are using for that

Comment: no. the method "setImage" starts and then directly there is this huge increase of memory usage. i think the problem is getResources() because it is the only thing i call when i start setImage